# Is it possible to display "menu" (my app) while watching TV program?

Tags: google-tv

I am new to Google TV but didn't find an answer for this...
Lets say the user is watching a channel, then press some button on the remote control:
Is it possible my app will then open kind of side bar with options for the user which the user will then choose from?

Please note - I do not need to mess up with the actual streaming currently running (the TV show).

Thanks in advance,
T.